# Replacing tabs in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I've got a `BottomNavigationView` featuring three tabs. The first tab depends on the state of the app (while the second and third will stay the the same).

The first tab will not be changed a lot, so it would be ok, maybe even better, if I don't hold on to it, but destroy the one currently not linked in the BottomNavigationView.

I thought of two ways to build this, but I'm not sure if one has a downside (or is not possible):

1. Starting with `Fragment` ***A***, *B* and *C*, I might somehow be
   able to change the fragments name in `mobile_navigation.xml` from
   FragmentA to FragmentD programmatically?

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/navigation_first"
       android:name="my.example.app.FragmentA"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/navigation_first"
       android:name="my.example.app.FragmentD"/>
   ```
2. Otherwise I could start with Fragments ***E***, *B* and *C*, with
   *E* having a fullsize sub-fragment thats either *A* oder *D*.

**What would be the best way to handle this?**

Examples below.

[image: Replacing tabs in BottomNavigationView]